# Firebase Cloud Function for updating a document's field an hour after a date given

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, schedule

guys
I'm very new to Cloud Functions and I need to solve this problem:

In my Firestore database I have a collection named "bookings" that stores documents of football games. These documents have a field called "startTime" (timestamp) and a field called "ended", that stores a bool.
Now, I want that an hour after the startTime, the field "ended" turns from false to true.

Anyone can solve this for me?
Thanks

I tried with setTimeout, but realized that the function would have been shut down after only ten minutes.

Comment: You'll need to employ [Google Cloud Task Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a Cloud Function to run in exactly one hour after a specific time, as explained in the article titled "[How to schedule a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks (to build a Firestore document TTL)](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a)".

This approach is based on Cloud Tasks and on two Cloud Functions:

- A Cloud Function to schedule a task;
- Another Cloud Function, of type HTTPS, for Cloud Tasks to invoke.

Concretely, in your case, the first Cloud Function shall be triggered when the field called `startTime` field is set. It is in this Cloud Function that you set the `scheduleTime` (in your case one hour after `startTime` value) for the Cloud Tasks that will trigger the second Cloud Function.

Then in this second Cloud Function, you set the the `ended` field to `true`.